# How can these documentation edits get in conflict?

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics

Today I was notified that my edit in [windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg) **versions**

[image: WinDbg versions]

is in conflict with this approved edit of [windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg) **debuggers**

[image: WinDbg debuggers]

How is that possible? IMHO they have nothing in common except the topic they are in.

Comment: Is the same topic...

Comment: Yeah that is stupid. The only thing they have in common is they were both proposed by someone named Thomas. Besides that, your suggestion was *older*, so if it was really a conflict, it shouldn't have let me approve the newer one without dealing with your earlier suggestion (either rejecting or approving it).

Comment: @Braiam: in Java, there are 20+ examples per topic, edited by 50+ people. Does this result in endless conflicts then?

Comment: Only if you manage to convince the system that you can make a conflict. I'm not actually sure what a conflict means, but since a topic is just a big chunk of text... I'm not too surprised.

Comment: @Braiam It's not, though. We do look at individual parts to see if we can disambiguate edits. This isn't something that existed in Q&A, though, so while we do reuse the diffing engine, the "is this a conflict?" stuff is brand new. Definitely sounds like there's a(nother) bug in there somewhere. We'll investigate.